# matlab & beagleboard xm

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, beagleboard

Can I install matlab on beagleboard xm (running ubuntu 12.04)? If I can't how can I run matlab on beagleboard xm. I installed octave and it runs perfect but I need to use Matlab.

Comment: These are the requirements : [System Requirements - Release 2012a](http://www.mathworks.ch/support/sysreq/current_release/linux.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [proper toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/embedded-coder/arm-adaptor.html), you could generate code than run on ARM processors like the [BeagleBoard](http://www.mathworks.com/academia/beagleboard/)

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is NO. zellus is correct. Matlab requires a SSE2 instruction set. All ARM chip does not support SSE2. Just different architecture. See the disscussion at Mathworks:
http://www.mathworks.co.kr/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/320518

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-B3MR75/

Answer (score 2):

Referring to [System Requirements - Release 2012a](http://www.mathworks.ch/support/sysreq/current_release/linux.html) MATLAB only runs on

> Any Intel or AMD x86 processor supporting SSE2 instruction set**

As stated on [BeagleBoard-xM Product Details](http://beagleboard.org/hardware-xM)

> BeagleBoard-xM delivers extra ARM ® Cortex TM-A8

is equipped with an ARM processor. Therefore I expect MATLAB not to run.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out you probably don't want to (or can) install Matlab on the beagleboard but have Matlab generate C-code that will run on the board. For this you will need either Matlab Coder or Matlab Embedded Coder. The embedded toolbox produces "better/cleaner" code but is pricier than its non-embedded alternative. Please also note that if you need to do the same with Matlab simulink models you need even more toolboxes.